# Merge two files using non-exact match in awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, merge, grep

I am trying to merge 2 files using awk. The first file looks like this

```
exm-IND1-200449980  1   202183358
exm-IND1-201453487  1   203186865
exm-IND10-102817747 10  102827758
```

File 2 looks like this

```
exm-IND1-200449980_ver3 -0.0676 0.9988
exm-IND1-201453487_ver1 0.0845  0.0163
exm-IND10-102817747_ver3    -0.1154 0.5166
```

I want to have the first column of File 2 added to the information in File1. I want it to match on the first column of both files, but ignoring the "_ver3" or "_ver1" fields. I can't strip this information off as it is needed.

I thought that grep would find non-exact matches but when I try

```
grep exm-INDI1-200449980_ver3 file1
```

nothing is returned

I have tried

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next;}$1 in a {print a[$1]" "$1" "$2" "$3}' file2 file1 > file3
```

But it isn't giving me any output, I think because it is searching for exact matches only?

File 2 has ~16,000 lines and File 1 has ~ 1,000,000 lines.

The output I'm looking for would be something like this,

```
exm-IND1-200449980 1 202183358 exm-IND1-20449980_ver3
exm-IND1-201453487 1 203186865 exm-IND1-201453487_ver1
```

Comment: 1mio lines? I would suggest to use Perl.

Comment: @bashophil I don't think 1M lines such as those shown in the question is really a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$ awk -F'_| *' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a{print a[$1],$1"_"$2}' file1 file2
exm-IND1-200449980  1   202183358 exm-IND1-200449980_ver3
exm-IND1-201453487  1   203186865 exm-IND1-201453487_ver1
exm-IND10-102817747 10  102827758 exm-IND10-102817747_ver3
```

Make sure you have enough memory to hold `file1` although by my estimation the file should be smaller then 50 megabytes which won't be a problem for most machines made in the last decade. If size does become a problem you should think about splitting the file down in to chunks (you could use the [split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) command for this).

Comment: Sorry, I've not been clear, I'll edit the question to show the desired output

Comment: Surely you could have managed to tweak the output yourself. I have made the change however it introduces redundancy as you already store the ID in the first field. If this solves your problem then please upvote and accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %f2;
open my $F2, '<', 'file2' or die $!;
while (<$F2>) {
    my ($id, $num) = split ' ', $_, 3;
    $id =~ s/_ver[0-9]+//;
    $f2{$id} = $num;
}

open my $F1, '<', 'file1' or die $!;
while (<$F1>) {
    my ($id) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    chomp;
    print $_, "\t", $f2{$id}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm going with the awk solution as my perl isn't good enough to understand what this is doing, but thanks!